# method call of a generic list with RTTI

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti

I don't know how to do this:

Having this objects:

```
TMyObject = class;

TMyList<T: TMyObject> = class(TList<T>)
public
     function Execute(aParam1, aParam2:string):boolean;
end;

TMyOtherObject = class(TMyObject)

TMyOtherList = class(TMyList<TMyOtherObject>);
```

How can I execute the "execute" function via rtti if I receive
a TMyOtherList object in a function param as an TObject?

Thanks.

Comment: The function is receiving a TObject reference.

Comment: I think it would be a really good idea to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than to ask for advice on how to implement your psuedo-strongly-typed solution to it.

Comment: Hi. The question is about how to call the method from an unit with no access to the final classes based on a generic (TMyList<T>). The unit only know the generic. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with RTTI, just use a cast:

```
(aObject as TMyOtherList).Execute(param1, param2);
```

If casting is not an option then use an interface.

Comment: Thank you David. But the function doesn't know nothing about TMyOtherList. Because of this I'm using RTTI. The function works over the metadata of the passed object. and call a function of the generic which is in the same unit of the function.